# Construction of the topological equivalence homeomorphism

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I am taking a course in dynamical systems and I am a bit lost with the following concept. Given the definition of topological equivalence:

> **Topological equivalence:** We say two flow $\phi$ and $\psi$ are topologically equivalent if there is a homeomorphism $f : X \to Y$, mapping orbits of $\psi$ to orbits of $\phi$ homeomorphically, and preserving the orientation of the orbits. In addition, one must line up the flow of time: for each $y \in Y$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that, if $0 < |s| < t < \delta$, and if $s$ is such that $\phi(h(y),s) = h \circ \psi(y,t)$, then $s > 0$.

I know the following linear systems are topologically equivalent, but I do not know how to find the homeomorphism $f$ or how to prove their equivalence:

$\begin{pmatrix}
 x' \\ y'
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x \\ y
\end{pmatrix}$

and

$\begin{pmatrix}
 x' \\ y'
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 4 \\ -4 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x \\ y
\end{pmatrix}$

Is there a method to find this homeomorphism or is it just pure intuition?

Besides, I do know, because this was stated as a counterexample to topologically equivalent $\nLeftrightarrow$ topologically conjugate, that the systems are not topologically conjugate, which is the same as topologically equivalent but without the lining up the flow of time. Why is this?

Comment: It seems to be the two matrices are the same up to a multiple of $4$, right? And scaling by $4$ is certainly a homeomorphism

Comment: I will rewrite the question since I think I missed a key question. Thank you for your response

Comment: It is easy to check the circles are periodic orbit rotating clockwise in both systems, so the identity on $\mathbb{R}^2$ would do.  But they have different periods ($2\pi$ for the first, $\pi/2$ for the second system) so you don't have topological conjugacy.

Comment: If you reparametrize the time in the first system, $t = 4\tau$ you obtain the second one one. Hence, the identity map maps the orbits of the first system into the orbits of the second. The parametrization is not taken into account by topological equivalence.